# How can I get a list of all open named pipes in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, pipe

Is there an easy way to test whether your named pipe is working correctly? I want to make sure that the data I'm sending from my app is actually being sent. Is there a quick and easy way to get a list of all the named pipes?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can view these with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from sysinternals.  Use the "Find -> Find Handle or DLL..." option and enter the pattern "\Device\NamedPipe\".  It will show you which processes have which pipes open.

Comment: Check which version of Process Explorer you have before you try this. It does not work on v15.23, but works on v16.02. (haven't tried other versions)

Comment: To avoid possible exceptions - as it is mentioned in other answers - you can use my solution which is more low level but working like a charm even if named pipe's name contains invalid characters in way of name of file. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109491/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-open-named-pipes-in-windows-and-avoiding-possible-ex/25126943#25126943

Comment: Using `pipelist.exe` from SysInternals is even simpler, but it's command line only.

Answer (score 138):

In the Windows Powershell console, type

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\")
```

---

If your OS version is greater than Windows 7, you can also type

```
get-childitem \\.\pipe\
```

This returns a list of objects. If you want the name only:

```
(get-childitem \\.\pipe\).FullName
```

In Powershell 7, the second example `\\.\pipe\` does not work (see this [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11898)), so you will have to stick to the first syntax.

Comment: You may want to consider opening Powershell as an administrator

Comment: You can also use get-childitem \\.\pipe\

Comment: @ChrisGillum I tried that, and got an error "Cannot find path '\\.\pipe\' because it does not exist"

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Interesting. What OS are you running on? It works for me on Windows Server 2012 and Windows 10 (PowerShell v3 and v5 respectively).

Comment: @ChrisGillum I'm testing it on Windows 7, Powershell v2.

Comment: @ChrisGillum But I just tried it on my Windows Surface RT device. It works there. (Powershell v4). I'll incorporate your comment into the answer.

Comment: Actually, I updated my Windows 7 machine to use Powershell 5. The second example still does not work on Windows 7. Where it works or not must depend on the OS, not the powershell version.

Comment: On Windows 10 (20H2), somehow the get-childitem variant works on Powershell 5 but not Powershell 7.

Comment: @Chih-HsuanYen - [It's a bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11898). This is the workaround: `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('\\.\pipe\')`

Answer (score 57):

Try the following instead:

```
String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");
```

Comment: your missing a slash.

string[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");

Comment: I spent all night looking for a function to search for or list pipes. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: What is this special path? \\.\ seems to be used for raw access to a drive, but where does `pipe` come from?

Comment: @Kevin "\\.\" means "this machine" as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/windows/desktop/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The best thing is, that also works in Powershell... `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\pipe")` Thanks!

Comment: We have had issues with this method working on windows 10 - getting error "Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.
Parameter name: path2 "

Comment: @DaiBok This is handled [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109491/806690).

Answer (score 52):

Use [pipelist.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd581625.aspx) from Sysinternals.

Comment: See also handle.exe from sysinternals which will show almost all things that have an open handle.

Answer (score 39):

I stumbled across a feature in Chrome that will list out all open named pipes by navigating to `file://.//pipe//`

Since I can't seem to find any reference to this and it has been very helpful to me, I thought I might share.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This does list my pipes. Amazing!
(note this will work because it works like a directory, as Andrew Shepherd's answer shows)

Comment: I guess this is for debugging/diagnostics, since I noticed Chrome uses a *lot* of named pipes - I found *125* "chrome" pipes even when Chrome isn't running!

Comment: Works for Edge as well. I suspect it works with any browser.

Comment: Daynew, awesome! Thanks alot. @JayElston, doesn't work in Firefox :( Chrome only.

Comment: @1234ru -- Thanks! I did just find Bug 500151 "No access to named pipes via Javascript chrome extensions" (filed in 2009, still OPEN) in Mozilla's Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500151). I just tried it in my AVG and Brave browsers and it works there.

Answer (score 26):

At `CMD` prompt:

```
>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476]

>dir \\.\pipe\\
```

Comment: Works on W10 but not on W7

Comment: Adding `/b` makes the output easier to deal with

Answer (score 19):

C#:

```
String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");
```

Answer (score 10):

The second pipe was interpreted by this web site when submitted... You need two backslashes at the beginning. So make sure to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\")`.

Note that I have seen this function call throw an 'illegal characters in path.' exception when one of the pipes on my machine had invalid characters. PipleList.exe worked ok though, so it seems like a bug in MS's .NET code.

Comment: The note about 'illegal characters in path' is an important point, because it is very common for programs to open pipe names that trigger this. Any program that opens a pipe named like `C:\myLocation\someFile.x` will cause this error.