# communication between c++ and c# through pipe

Tags: c#, c++, ipc

I want to send data from a c# application to a c++ application through a pipe.
Here is what I've done:

this is the c++ client:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

  HANDLE hFile;
  BOOL flg;
  DWORD dwWrite;
  char szPipeUpdate[200];
  hFile = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\BvrPipe", GENERIC_WRITE,
                             0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                             0, NULL);

  strcpy(szPipeUpdate,"Data from Named Pipe client for createnamedpipe");
  if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  { 
      DWORD dw = GetLastError();
      printf("CreateFile failed for Named Pipe client\n:" );
  }
  else
  {
      flg = WriteFile(hFile, szPipeUpdate, strlen(szPipeUpdate), &dwWrite, NULL);
      if (FALSE == flg)
      {
         printf("WriteFile failed for Named Pipe client\n");
      }
      else
      {
         printf("WriteFile succeeded for Named Pipe client\n");
      }
      CloseHandle(hFile);
  }
return 0;
```

}

and here the c# server

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
namespace PipeApplication1{

class ProgramPipeTest
{

    public void ThreadStartServer()
    {
        // Create a name pipe
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("\\\\.\\pipe\\BvrPipe"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Server] Pipe created {0}", pipeStream.GetHashCode());

            // Wait for a connection
            pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("[Server] Pipe connection established");

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
            {
                string temp;
                // We read a line from the pipe and print it together with the current time
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, temp);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Connection lost");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramPipeTest Server = new ProgramPipeTest();

        Thread ServerThread = new Thread(Server.ThreadStartServer);

        ServerThread.Start();

    }
}
```

}

when I start the server and then the client GetLastErrror from client returns 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Any idea on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say you don't need the "\.\Pipe\" prefix when creating the pipe in the server. The [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) of calling the NamedPipeServerStream constructor that I've seen just pass-in the pipe name. E.g.

```
using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("BvrPipe"))
```

You can list the open pipes, and their names, using SysInternals process explorer. This should help you verify that the pipe has the correct name. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258701/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-open-named-pipes-in-windows) question for details.

Comment: I can confirm this, I have used pipes between C# and C++, and I did not use the Pipe\ prefix on the pipe name when creating a NamedPipeServerStream.

Comment: In the above Code, till we call CloseHandle on pipe handle from C++ code, data is not passed to C# Server . Is there any way to pass without closing handle ? I tried "FlushFileBuffers" function also. It dint work

Comment: @Raveendra You can't flush a socket. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814835/flush-a-socket-in-c for info. Also see http://www.tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#packetscheme.

Answer (score -1):

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365603(VS.85).aspx) to see how the pipes are implemented. Why are you not using CreateNamedPipes API call? You are treating the file handle on the C++ side as an ordinary file not a pipe. Hence your C++ code fails when it is looking for a pipe when in fact it was attempting to read from a file.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to use CreateFile() to open the _client_ end of a pipe. See the Remarks section for the CreateFile function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @andyjohnson: I wasn't aware that you could do that...my bad...sorry for the misleading statement... :(