# How can I get a list of Anonymous pipes opened

Tags: windows, winapi, anonymous-pipes

As a follow up to the older question : [How can I get a list of all open named pipes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258701/1068609) , I am in a situation where I need to check if a process uses anonymous pipes to communicate with its children. Is there a way to do this ? I've tried pipelist and process-explorer but it looks like they display only lists of NamedPipes

Comment: Process Explorer has an option to show anonymous objects.

Comment: Do you  mean the option to display an un-named handles and objects ?

Comment: Yes. <!-- padding :) -->

Answer (score 0):

@Deanna : As an answer to close this topic
Indeed procExplorer lists all anonymous objects. But it is not yet possible to view anonymous pipes specifically. Which leads me to assume that, one cannot determine with absolute certainty the un-named pipes used by a process