# Windows: Check existence of named pipe

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

I am writing a C++ program that makes use of named pipes on Windows. I can create and work with them quite fine. The only piece missing to the puzzle is a function to check for a pipe's existence.

Coming from the Unix world I originally tried `std::filesystem::exists("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe")` but this is not reliable and often errors with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`.

While searching for an alternative way to check for a pipe's existence, I stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process/issues/4) on GitHub (Boost process) and from there I take it that Boos process circumvents the problem by using a special naming scheme and a counter and then keeping track of that internally (only seems to work for pipes created via Boost process though).

Furthermore according to [How can I get a list of all open named pipes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258701/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-open-named-pipes-in-windows) it seems that there are ways to list the existing named pipes. These solutions are not using C++ though and I did not find a way to port that over.

After having read the [documentation of CreateNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea), I now assembled the following solution to my problem:

```
bool NamedPipe::exists(const std::filesystem::path &pipePath) {
    if (pipePath.parent_path() != "\\\\.\\pipe") {
        // This can't be a pipe, so it also can't exist
        return false;
    }

    // Attempt to create a pipe with FILE_FLAG_FIRST_INSTANCE so that the creation will fail
    // if the pipe already exists
    HANDLE pipeHandle = CreateNamedPipe(pipePath.string().c_str(),
                                        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
                                        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                                        1,   // # of allowed pipe instances
                                        0,   // Size of outbound buffer
                                        0,   // Size of inbound buffer
                                        0,   // Use default wait time
                                        NULL // Use default security attributes
    );

    if (pipeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Creation has failed
        // It has failed (most likely) due to there alredy existing a pipe with
        // that name
        return true;
    } else {
        // The creation has succeeded
        if(!CloseHandle(pipeHandle)) {
            throw PipeException< DWORD >(GetLastError(), "CheckExistance");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

However attempting to create a named pipe only to check whether there already exists one with that name already seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead. Furthermore I am unsure of whether this solution is universally applicable or only works if the pipe tested for was also created with `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE`.

Therefore my question is: Is there a better way to check whether a named pipe with the given name already exists in Windows?

Comment: I don't see a reason to want to have that function. The only thing it provides is a TOCTTOU race. Not required for robust software.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to use this in my unit tests checking that a the pipe has been created and afterwards removed again as I expected. I don't intend on using that in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::filesystem::exists("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe")` returning `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` means it is using `CreateFile()` to actually connect to the pipe.  It is not unreasonable for an `exists()` implementation to attempt to open the requested file to check its existance.

Per the [`CreateFile()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew):

> If there is at least one active pipe instance but there are no available listener pipes on the server, which means all pipe instances are currently connected, `CreateFile` fails with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`.

Which means the pipe does technically exist, it is not ready to receive a new client at that moment.

In [the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258701/), many of the solutions provided suggest using .NET's `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` method to iterate though the contents of `"\\.\pipe\"`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25126943/65863) shows how that call translates into Win32 API calls using `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()`. You can easily do the same API calls in C++, eg:

```cpp
bool NamedPipe::exists(const std::filesystem::path &pipePath)
{
    std::string pipeName = pipePath.string();
    if ((pipeName.size() < 10) ||
        (pipeName.compare(0, 9, "\\\\.\\pipe\\") != 0) ||
        (pipeName.find('\\', 9) != std::string::npos))
    {
        // This can't be a pipe, so it also can't exist
        return false;
    }
    pipeName.erase(0, 9);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    DWORD dwErrCode;

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\*", &fd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwErrCode = GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (pipeName == fd.cFileName)
            {
                FindClose(hFind);
                return true;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &fd));

        dwErrCode = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    if ((dwErrCode != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) &&
        (dwErrCode != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES))
    {
        throw PipeException< DWORD >(dwErrCode, "CheckExistance");
    }

    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**: or, using `std::wstring` with Unicode APIs instead, since the filesystem is natively Unicode on Windows:

```cpp
bool NamedPipe::exists(const std::filesystem::path &pipePath)
{
    std::wstring pipeName = pipePath;
    if ((pipeName.size() < 10) ||
        (pipeName.compare(0, 9, L"\\\\.\\pipe\\") != 0) ||
        (pipeName.find(L'\\', 9) != std::string::npos))
    {
        // This can't be a pipe, so it also can't exist
        return false;
    }
    pipeName.erase(0, 9);

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;
    DWORD dwErrCode;

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\*", &fd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        dwErrCode = GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (pipeName == fd.cFileName)
            {
                FindClose(hFind);
                return true;
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &fd));

        dwErrCode = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    if ((dwErrCode != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) &&
        (dwErrCode != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES))
    {
        throw PipeException< DWORD >(dwErrCode, "CheckExistance");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that this code as it is listed here does not compile. There are a few typos in variable names and the path has to be converted to a string by an explicit call to `path::string()`. For some reason I can't suggest an edit to fix this myself though.

Comment: @Raven I only see 1 variable typo, I have corrected it. `std::filesystem::path` has an [implicit conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native) to `std::basic_string<path::value_type>`, but I guess that resolves to `std::wstring` on Windows, so I have added the explicit call to `string()` instead.  Probably should be using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, though. I have added a 2nd example for that.

Comment: You are using `hFind` and `hFile` for the same variable. If the `hFile` variable is renamed to `hFind`, then everything works like charm. Thanks for the update though :+1: