# Getting a list of named pipes on Windows using win32api?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

You could get your users to install the [pipelist utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist), and then process the output of:

```
subprocess.check_output("pipelist", universal_newlines=True)
```

Using C#, [one can also do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252118/3486684):

```
String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");
```

Is there a way to replicate this C# solution using `pywin32`/`win32api`?

Comment: The FindFirstFile & friends APIs will accept "\\.\pipe\" - it may even work with os.listdir out of the box.

Comment: `os.listdir('\\\\.\\pipe')` works!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani You are a genius who needs to write an answer that I can upvote and accept.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the answer from @AlexK though!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Ah. Ididn't see his edit! I thin his original comment didn't include `os.listdir`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in comment

```
import os
arr = os.listdir('\\\\.\\pipe')
print (arr)
```

Comment: "\Device\NamedPipe" is a filesystem, implemented by the filesystem driver "\FileSystem\Npfs". It's not a complete filesystem, though. It doesn't implement all system calls that are expected of a filesystem. But it does implement `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, so it can be used with WinAPI `FindFirstFile`, etc.