# How to see named pipe permission from command line on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, named-pipes

I've got an existing named pipe, say `\\.\pipe\my_pipe`. How can I, from cmd or powershell, get the ACL/Permissions of the pipe ?

Comment: [accesschk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk) checks a named pipe when the path is prefixed with "\pipe", e.g. `accesschk -lv \pipe\InitShutdown`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool [NtObjectManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NtObjectManager/1.1.33) by James Forshaw.
After installing it, open PowerShell with Admin rights and run:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $a = Get-NtNamedPipeFile "\Device\NamedPipe\spoolss"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $a.SecurityDescriptor.Dacl

Type    User                         Flags Mask
----    ----                         ----- ----
Allowed BUILTIN\Users                None  00100003
Allowed Everyone                     None  001201BB
Allowed NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON None  001201BB
Allowed CREATOR OWNER                None  001F01FF
Allowed NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM          None  001F01FF
Allowed BUILTIN\Administrators       None  001F01FF
```

Answer (score 0):

This tool helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/accesschk

In PowerShell:
.\accesschk64.exe \.\pipe<name>

Comment: Building an answer based on existing comments is acceptable, but you ought to credit the comment author (in this case [@ErykSun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923402/how-to-see-named-pipe-permission-from-command-line-on-windows#comment84853676_48923402))

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon [this answer from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066420/7163041):

```
Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | ForEach-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue GetAccessControl
```

You can also use `Get-Member` to help you navigate the `FileSecurity` object:

```
Get-ChildItem \\.\pipe\ | ForEach-Object -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue GetAccessControl | Get-Member
```

Answer (score -1):

`ls '\\.\pipe\' | % { try{ $_.GetAccessControl() } catch{"nope"}}`