# Simply way of getting all open named pipes

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

Is there a simpel way to get all open named pipes in c++, like there is in c#?

```
String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");
```

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258701/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-open-named-pipes-in-windows) where differen methodes where proposed to get all open named pipes, unfortunately nothing for c++ c0x.

Comment: As long as you’re on Windows, the exact same code works in C++. Just use the C++ functions for doing directory listings.

Comment: C++0x? Not even C++11? You'd need C++17 for this.

Comment: check [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-type-read-and-wait-modes) for appropriate  API

Comment: Main idea - named pipes is not a c++ feature, but windows specific api. It's pretty outdated and i think doesn't really have any improvements like c# have. So you probably should build something like this yourself using api from documentation I linked above

Comment: i have to add an feature to old legacy code, im working with Visualstudio 2008. The server, client and communication part is already working. But at the moment i have to enter the named pipe name/handel hardcoded.

Comment: @MSalters Of course you *don’t* need C++17. OP is writing code for Windows. WinAPI is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much of .NET's source code is openly available on https://referencesource.microsoft.com.

If you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs) for the [`System.IO.Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netcore-3.1) class, its [`GetFiles()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,f9704790d3b23471) method creates a `TList<String>` using an `IEnumerable<String>` from [`FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileNameIterator()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs,6476afd28f7cc308), and then converts that `TList<String>` to a `String[]` array, where [`FileSystemEnumerableIterator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs,e9aaa9fc3bf05462) internally uses the Win32 API [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [`FindNextFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) functions.

So, the statement:

```cs
String[] listOfPipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\");
```

Would be roughly equivalent to the following C++ code using the Win32 API directly:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::wstring> listOfPipes;

std::wstring prefix(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\");

WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW((prefix + L"*").c_str(), &fd);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // error handling...
}
else
{
    do
    {
        listOfPipes.push_back(prefix + fd.cFileName);
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &fd));

    // error handling...

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Since you can't use C++17, you'll need the WinAPI way of iterating over a directory. That's `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile`. Despite the name, that will also find pipes if you look in `\\.\pipe\`.

Comment: It should be expected. The named-pipe filesystem (NPFS) has a root directory at `"\\Device\\NamedPipe\\"` (i.e. `"\\\\.\\PIPE\\"`) that contains named pipe files and supports directory queries such as `FileDirectoryInformation`. Interestingly, NPFS doesn't support subdirectories, so slashes are allowed in names. Also, in the directory entry, the allocation size is the max number of instances, and the size is current number. But in the standard info of an instance of the pipe, the allocation size is the total quota in bytes, and the size is the number of bytes queued at the queried pipe end.